# D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile produces Access violation writing location error

Tags: directx

I have a piece of code written below and I'm stuck with it. I've done it before with a different compiler and right now I'm moving into the Visual C++. Every time this function tries to get called this error pops out:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0076e124 in SeaQuest.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0xccccccd0.

Besides, I've written the D3DXGetImageInfoFromFileA's syntax correctly.

```
class Texture
{
private:
  D3DXIMAGE_INFO m_ImageInfo;
public:
  bool GetImageInfo(char* filename);
};

bool Texture::GetImageInfo(char* filename)
{
  if((D3DXGetImageInfoFromFileA(filename, &m_ImageInfo)) != D3D_OK)
    return false; 
}
```

I've also tracked the DirectX debug output but it doesn't show anything.

**UPDATE**

Now I've defined a D3DXIMAGE_INFO local variable in the implementation of GetImageInfo and have it addressed instead of m_ImageInfo. It works!. I don't know what is the problem with my private member that the `Access violation writing` rises for that. Hope someone guide me.

**ANSWER**

I was using Texture class as a pointer variable in another class and the reason was to not instantiating the pointer to a new Texture class or I could use a non pointer variable then copy class into it but losing the benefits of referencing. `0xC0000005` is near to 0 so it means there is a NULL pointer that it's trying to get addressed. I'll keep it in mind hope you will too!

Comment: What do you mean that you declared D3DXIMAGE_INFO correctly? They are part of DirectX and do not need to be redeclared. Furthermore, why do you use D3DXGetImageInfoFromFileA instead of D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile?

Comment: Sorry for wrong word using! I meant, I write the D3DXIMAGE_INFO's syntax correctly as it should be passed by reference `&`. For the second question, Because I didn't set the project to Multi-Byte so it's still using Unicode.